# Salaried Payroll Conversion Semi-Monthly to Bi-Weekly

Tags: payroll

Our finance team wants to move the semi-monthly employees who are all salaried to a bi-weekly pay schedule on August 16th. The ongoing argument is the "gap" in pay. 
We've been using an example of an employee who earns $50k per year. At the end of 2021 they will get $48,557.64.
15 checks @ $2.083.33
9 checks @ 1,923.08

I understand that by going bi-weekly, they will receive a portion of their 2021 time worked in 2022, but how do they ever "catch up"? Salaried employees who are already bi-weekly received EOY 2020 pay in 2021, but that's not the case for the people being converted.

Also, what do companies typically do to assist the employees when they go an extra week without pay due to the conversion? Does everyone just give plenty of notice so the employee can plan?

I apologize if I'm not explaining this well, or maybe we've just over complicated it.

Our Conversion Example:
[image]

Comment: The employees are currently being paid as much as three days *in advance*.  How will the employer ever "catch up"?

Comment: Where did the $1923.08 figure come from? After 8/13, your employee is still owed 18750.05, which split across 9 additional payments is still ~2083. Note that they are getting paid *three* times in October, instead of only (presumably) on 10/15 and 10/29. Effectively, 9/3 is the missing August check, and 9/17 and 10/1 are the old-style September checks.

Comment: This would be a better question for https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ as it isn't about personal finance.

Answer (score 2):

If you took the semi-monthly employees and delayed payday the until the next Thursday, then those employees would also receive part of their December pay in January. You are doing two things: Switching the pay frequency and going to a system that delays checks.

I have lived though both of these things, just never at the same time.

My suggestion would be to pick a different date to make the change. Pick a date that results in the last paycheck of the year hitting the bank on December 30th. That might require a delay until next year.  One company that tried this had to delay for a year because they didn't consider any of the impacts, and gave no notice. They delayed because of the massive number of complaints.

You could also make this a two step process. Do one this year and the other next year.

> Does everyone just give plenty of notice so the employee can plan?

This part is a US based answer: Keep in mind that this change will also impact insurance premiums, 401(k) contributions. It can also impact Flex spending and HSA contributions. If they were trying to meet a minimum  or maximum amount, the change in pay frequency needs to be accounted for. It can also impact PTO hours earned.

The company has to be prepared to make these adjustments automatic for the employee. They don't want to risk leaving money on the table.

> Also, what do companies typically do to assist the employees when they
> go an extra week without pay due to the conversion?

In my experience when there was a one week delay added to the system, the company compensated by overpaying everybody by a week, and then taking it back over several  months. For example paying an extra 40 hours, and then pulling back 4 hours per check for the next 10 paychecks.